# What skill covers warfare?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, skills

I want to build a character who's participated in many of the wars near and in the Worldwould. I'm not sure what skill covers this background. I thought something like Craft (warfare) might be appropriate, but the game doesn't support such a specialty. What skill best represents knowledge of warfare and participation in a lot of battles?

I want to develop towards an expert of tactics so people beliefe in me when I tell them what to do, due to my experience. Later on I want to combine this with Leadership and Mystic Marshall.

Comment: What all specifically do you want the skill to reflect? I edited your other comment in... If you want a skill that makes you better in tactics in some concrete way you probably need to have a discussion with your GM, because they're not guaranteed to interpret Craft/Prof skills past their "make some money" RAW in a consistent way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Profession: soldier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/profession) is the usual answer to this.  But it does depend what exactly you mean and want to do - there's profession:siege engineer, etc. for the many, many aspects of warfare.